# Problem with slow computer

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have an older windows vista PC. I haven't been using it, and loaded Ubuntu 14 on it. It seems to load OK, but the older system seems to be over loaded. It just freezes after entering my password. Are there ways to still use it? I saw that it was recommended to update the graphics card to NVIDIA, did that. So that helped it boot faster, and the screen doesn't go pixelated like it did previously. Now though it just freezes after password ad can't get farther than that. Are there items I can turn off or change while in safe mode that will make it run? I read that Unity doesn't have to be running? Help please.

Thanks!

Comment: is it 64 bit or 32 bit? how much ram? - it will be helpful to add some specifics about the machine

Comment: Did you install using WUBI? Wubi installs are notoriously buggy, and lead to much slower systems.